# Out of memory at every second trial using Ray Tune

Tags: tensorflow, ray, ray-tune

I am tuning the hyperparameters using ray tune. The model is built in the tensorflow library, it occupies a large part of the available GPU memory. I noticed that every second call reports an out of memory error.It looks like the memory is being freed, you can see in the GPU memory usage graph, this is the moment between calls of consecutive trials, between which the OOM error occurred. I add that on smaller models I do not encounter this error and the graph looks the same.

How to deal with this out of memory error in every second trial ?

[image: Memory usage graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a utility that helps avoid this:

https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/api_docs/trainable.html#ray.tune.utils.wait_for_gpu

```
def tune_func(config):
    tune.utils.wait_for_gpu()
    train()

tune.run(tune_func, resources_per_trial={"GPU": 1}, num_samples=10)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, I added this line at the beginning of my function and I get the same results, every second call ends with OOM

Comment: Hmm is it possible that somehow GPU memory is being used due to deserialization?

Comment: For example, if you didn't call `train` and only did `wait_for_gpu`, does it still OOM?

Comment: Thank you for your reply the advice was useful, however the problem lay in using tensorflow earlier than as a trial. Additionally, the function wait_for_gpu had a bug, which I solved by creating the function from scratch.

Comment: When I try this I get "AttributeError: module 'ray.tune' has no attribute 'util'"

Comment: should be 'utils' sorry.